# Join on two tables from the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I have the following tables...

```
class QuestionEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "recipient_id"
```

...this allows me to do...

```
2.1.5 :001 > qe = QuestionEvent.find 475282
  QuestionEvent Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `question_events`.* FROM `question_events` WHERE `question_events`.`id` = 475282 LIMIT 1
 => #<QuestionEvent id: 475282, question_id: 112307, initiated_by_id: 17, recipient_id: 10696, "2013-03-13 13:08:14", updated_at: "2013-03-13 13:08:14", updated_question_values: nil, changed_tag: nil>
2.1.5 :002 > qe.recipient
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 10696 LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

What I am looking for is a query I can run from the console that show me all QuestionEvents where `recipients` is nil. In the case above, there is a recipient_id, however, that id is not in the User table.

I tried something like `QuestionEvent.includes(:recipient).where("recipient_id", nil)` but no cigar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
QuestionEvent.where("question_events.recipient_id NOT IN (?)", User.pluck(:id))
```

Answer (score 1):

we can use 2 queries

```
user_ids = User.pluck(:id)
QuestionEvent.where("recipient_id NOT IN (?)", user_ids)
```